# Слетел GRUB, не могу запустить систему

Tags: ubuntu, grub, linux

На ноуте стоит убунту 11.04 и ХР При очередном запуске системы увидел error:

> `unknown filesystem. grub rescue>_`

Есть загрузочный с ХР, но без Live CD. Есть в нём утилита для проверки харда, но выдаёт ошибку, партишен нашел bad сектор, думаю загрузочный. Погуглив нашел, какие команды можно ввести, но ноут говорит, что команд этих не знает. LiveCD убунты нет и нет возможности скачать, может кто проинструктирует, что можно сделать?

Comment: А grub то сам хоть загружается? В его shell можно попасть?

Comment: нет вижу только unknown filesystem. grub rescue>_пробовал вводить команду is, set root ничего, говорит не знает команд

Answer (score 1):

Грузитесь с любого livecd дистрибутива linux, далее через `chroot` входите в "поломаную" ОС и пропишите `update-grub`.

Comment: Всем спасибо, как я и ожидал, без Live CD проблему не решить,поставил на закачку с чужего компа, через пару дней обещает скачать

Comment: @max-02 есть очень маленькие rescue образы для флешек.

Answer (score 0):

Подробнее расписано [здесь](http://ubuntologia.ru/blog/system/29.html)